# Error opening an image with OpenCV and matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv

I am following [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-opencv-color-spaces/) for python and I'm stuck. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nemo = cv2.imread('./images/nemo0.jpg')
plt.imshow(nemo)
plt.show()
```

As you might see I am using the same code there is in the tutorial, but the python terminal comes up with this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScriptPython.py", line 6, in <module>
    plt.imshow(cv2.imread('./Escritorio/nemo0.jpg'))
  File "/home/ghost/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2677, in imshow
    None else {}), **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghost/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1599, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghost/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghost/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 369, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ghost/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5679, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/ghost/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 685, in set_data
    "float".format(self._A.dtype))
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

I think I have every needed package, and I'm using python3.6. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your path to image is not correct. OpenCV doesn't complain when it fails to find image at specified location, thus mostly likely `nemo` object is None. This simply means that it is your responsibility to make sure image is in correct path. However, you may check your object against `None` before passing it on to matplotlib, like this:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nemo = cv2.imread('./images/nemo0.jpg')
if(nemo is not None):
    plt.imshow(nemo)
    plt.show()
else:
    print('Image is not loaded')
```

If you see that your program is printing `Image is not loaded`, then you must verify your image path. Please note that `.` in path means start looking from current directory.